# Chrubuntu 12.04 Bluetooth not detecting devices

Tags: bluetooth, chrubuntu

I have Chrubuntu running on an Acer c710. It seems like most people had Bluetooth working right away. I Am having a problem with it. The Bluetooth manager allows me to turn the adapter on and off, but I can't connect to anything.

If I search from my phone I can't find the computer. If I search from the manager I can't find my phone, my headphones or my home stereo. I have tried the default manager, `blueman` and `bluedevil` extension to KDE. Nothing works.

I know people have had this problem with the Realink card and have fixed it by going into Windows and turning it on there but there is no option to turn it on in Chrome OS. Besides, it's not a Realink card. I opened it up and the card says Atheros model #: ar5b22. It's a combo wifi Bluetooth card.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. Not every acer c710 came with the same adapter. The one that is in mine is the Atheros AR5B22 also known as theAR9462 . This card has a known issue linux.

There is a fix here but it does not work with the chrubuntu kernal: 
http://orkultus.wordpress.com/tag/bluetooth-ar9462-linux-linuxmint-ubuntu/

I replaced the Atheros card with a Intel Centrino 2230 i bought on ebay for $13. 2 min. install.

Bluetooth now works perfectly. (along with WIFI)